# Pass function into React Navigation's headerTitle component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a deletePost button, but I'm struggling to pass it into my header component. Here's the

```
export class PostScreen extends Component {


  // Custom headerTitle component.
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    return { headerTitle: <PostTitle {...params} handleDelete={this.handleDelete}/> }
  };

  handleDelete = async (id) => {
    const { deletePost } = this.props;
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    deletePost(token, id);
  }

render() {
```

This does'nt seem to be the right way to pass it in. What's the correct way? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Are you sure this is `react-native-navigation` and not `react-navigation`?

Comment: @Andrew ah right, it is `react-navigation`

Comment: Where are you getting the id from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are using `react-navigation` then this is how you set a function in the header component.

1. You have to define the function in your class
2. In your `componentDidMount` set the function as a param using `setParam`
3. Use `getParam` in your navigation header.

This is how it would look in a very simple component.

```
export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state; // this is included because you had added it and you may require the params in your component
    return {
      headerTitle: <PostTitle  {...params} handleDelete={navigation.getParam('handleDelete')} />, // grab the function using getParam
    };
  };

  handleDelete = () => {
    alert('delete')
  }

  // set the function as a param in your componentDidMount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleDelete: this.handleDelete });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Screen1</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in your `PostTitle` component you can use the function that you just passed by calling `this.props.handleDelete`

Here is a snack that shows the basic functionality https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/functions-in-a-navigation-header

You can read more about setting functions in the navigation header [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I still get a Failed prop type when the component first mounts. Is there anyway I can set the prop before the it mounts?

Comment: Which prop is failing?

Comment: the handleDelete function. When the component first mounts it's not available, then componentDidMount makes it available

Comment: I am guessing it is in the `PostTitle` component where it is complaining you could set a default value for the prop

Comment: yeah, I was thinking worst case scenario, I'd just remove 'isRequired'

Comment: One of those two are your pretty much your options.

Answer (score 0):

in your component did mount use an arrow function as below and the function won't be called when the component first mount.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleDelete: (() => this.handleDelete()) 
});
```